# How to align a vector to another one?

Tags: vectors

I have a given vector (a surface normal), and a second vector (pointing up).
How would i have to manipulate the second vector, to make it point in the same direction as my surface vector?
example:

surface $vec_3(0, 0, 1)$;

second $vec_3 (0, 0.8, 0.3)$;

result $vec_3(0, 0.3, 0.8)$;

basically have my second vectors $y$-axis aligned with my surface vector.

here is an example image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAWZX.jpg

Comment: Adding $v_1=(0,0,-0.7)$ and $v_2=(0,0.8,0)$ to $(0,0,1)$ won't do the trick?

Comment: this would not work for any second vector. keep in mind, that the second vector varies. this is just an example.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. What is the $y$ axis of a vector? In your picture, is the dotted vector always the surface normal? It sounds like you are trying to project the second vector onto the surface vector.